# SQL Server XML Parsing Null Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Hello I have procedure like below

```
USE [DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdminTestSaveAnswer]
    @refQuestion xml
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT  
       Tbl.Col.value('@Id', 'int'),  
       Tbl.Col.value('@Question', 'varchar(max)'),  
       Tbl.Col.value('@CorrectAnswer', 'varchar(7)'),
       Tbl.Col.value('@Desc', 'varchar(max)')
    FROM   @refQuestion.nodes('//Root') Tbl(Col)

END
```

I run code like

```
EXEC [dbo].[SP_AdminTestSaveAnswer] '<Root>
  <Id>2</Id>
  <Question>(I) Yaşayan sanatçılara televizyonlarda pek yer verilmiyor. (II) Bunların içerisinde sürekli olarak ekranda olan tek sanatçı neredeyse Attila İlhan. (III) Demek ki ülkemizde edebiyatçılara, şairlere, romancılara, öykü ve deneme ustalarına ihtiyaç duyulmuyor artık. (III) Şahsen ben 1996’dan beri televizyonlarda anımsanmıyor, oralara çağrılmıyorum. (V) Diğer pek çok yazarın da akla geldiğini, zaman zaman da olsa ekrana davet edildiklerini sanmıyorum.
&lt;/br&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;b&gt;
Bu parçadaki numaralanmış cümlelerin hangisinde bir çıkarım söz konusudur?&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</Question>
  <CorrectAnswer>A</CorrectAnswer>
  <Desc>deded</Desc>
  <refTest>1</refTest>
  <Answers>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Answer>I.</Answer>
    <Code>A</Code>
    <refQuestion>0</refQuestion>
  </Answers>
  <Answers>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Answer>II.</Answer>
    <Code>B</Code>
    <refQuestion>0</refQuestion>
  </Answers>
  <Answers>
    <Id>4</Id>
    <Answer>III.</Answer>
    <Code>C</Code>
    <refQuestion>0</refQuestion>
  </Answers>
  <Answers>
    <Id>5</Id>
    <Answer>IV.</Answer>
    <Code>D</Code>
    <refQuestion>0</refQuestion>
  </Answers>
  <Answers>
    <Id>6</Id>
    <Answer>V.</Answer>
    <Code>E</Code>
    <refQuestion>0</refQuestion>
  </Answers>
</Root>'
```

As result I get one row but all of columns are null. Where is my missing ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI the `sp_` prefix is reserved by Microsoft and should **not** be used for User Procedures. Doing so has multiple implications, including performance and reliability.

Comment: As for why, `@Id` would reference the property `Id` not the Node; you want `(/Id/text())[1]`. Also `//Root` should be `/Root`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@` is for xml attrubites, your data is in elements.  So should be something like

```
SELECT  
   Tbl.Col.value('Id[1]', 'int'),  
   Tbl.Col.value('Question[1]', 'varchar(max)'),  
   Tbl.Col.value('CorrectAnswer[1]', 'varchar(7)'),
   Tbl.Col.value('Desc[1]', 'varchar(max)')
FROM   @refQuestion.nodes('/Root') Tbl(Col)
```